# How to delete a table with code?

Tags: dml

I want to delete a custom table using a code (not UI).
Something like `DELETE My_Object__c` returns exception.

Can I do that ?

Comment: You need to pass an instance that has its `Id` value set so the system knows which record to delete.

Comment: @KeithC, i want to delete table, not record

Comment: @NazarSokhan Sorry, my bad. Best you explain __why__ in your question as such a delete is a lot easier done manually.

Comment: @KeithC, but is it possible to do this with code?

Comment: Yes it is possible - see sfdcfox's answer - but dependencies can block the delete and it can only be done by a (dangerously high) privilege user. That is, there are enough gotchas that it is only a mechanism to use in narrow circumstances.

Comment: @KeithC thank you for answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with the [Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deploy_deleting_files.htm). If you're using Apex, try using the [Metadata Wrapper](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi). You can't just ordinarily delete an object with a single line of code, it's more complicated than that.